# Representing memory using hashtable from a text file

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I have a project where I need to create a memory management program in Java and I have the text file but don't know where to begin. I'm already familiar with the `split()` method in Java, but basically I want the index as the key and everything that comes after as a value.

Here's the text file cus it's big AF: https://pastebin.com/Q4whQHxW

Code:

```java
String[] temp;
temp = data.split("\n"); //assume data is the string that contains the text 
//doc contents
String[][] temp2 = new String[temp.length][];

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    temp2[i] = temp[i].split("( )");
}
for(int i = 0; i < temp2.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < temp2[i].length; j++)
        memoryPhysical.put(Integer.parseInt(temp2[i][0]),temp2[i][j]);
}
System.out.println(memoryPhysical);
```

Comment: Is your code working? If not, what seems to be the trouble?

Comment: What is the question here? Stack Overflow is not a code review portal

Comment: Do you really need a map if the "key" in each line is the number from 0 to N?  It seems that a list is more appropriate to store the values after the row number.

Comment: key value and value can be determined as follows: int key = Integer.parseInt(temp[i].split(" ")[0]); and value can be determined as follows:String val = temp[i].replaceFirst("[0-9]+ ","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map for key-value values. If you have any restrictions for using Map, let me know to write an array example. The code below shows you how to use Map:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "0 96\n" +
                "1 29\n" +
                "2 304\n" +
                "3 561\n" +
                "4 742\n" +
                "5 621\n" +
                "6 620\n" +
                "11605 sub %14922, 12566\n" +
                "11606 mov %15653, %12958";

        HashMap<Integer, String> items = new HashMap<>();

        Arrays.stream(text.split("\n")).forEach((s) -> {
            int splitIndex = s.indexOf(" ");
            String key = s.substring(0, splitIndex);
            String value = s.substring(splitIndex);

            items.put(Integer.parseInt(key), value);
        });

        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

Output:

{0= 96, 1= 29, 2= 304, 3= 561, 4= 742, 5= 621, 11605= sub %14922, 12566, 6= 620, 11606= mov %15653, %12958}

Comment: Why do you need a list of hashmaps?

Comment: You're right. Let me update the code.